# JQuery isn't work with reactjs. How to integrate Jquery in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to work with jQuery's Datatable JS for my project.

I downloaded a Bootstrap template and that integrated with in the reactjs project.

```
 <table className="table table-striped table-bordered dom-jQuery-events">
```

In my code "dom-jQuery-events" is active the jQuery table. And I also used the script tag in public/index.html file like this

```
<script src="assets/app-assets/js/scripts/tables/datatables/datatable-advanced.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The template that I downloaded is working correctly, but that code doesn't work in my react project.

Console shows an error:

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

I added my jQuery file path:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdngQ.png)

and my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /***************************************
     *       js of dom jQuery events        *
     ***************************************/

    var eventsTable = $('.dom-jQuery-events').DataTable();

    $('.dom-jQuery-events tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert('You clicked on ' + data[0] + '\'s row');
    });


    /***************************************
     *        js of column rendering        *
     ***************************************/

    $('.column-rendering').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
            // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
            // this case `data: 0`.
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                return data + ' (' + row[3] + ')';
            },
            "targets": 0
        }, {
            "visible": false,
            "targets": [3]
        }]
    });

    /******************************************************
     *        js of multiple table control elements        *
     ******************************************************/

    $('.multiple-control-elements').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>'
    });


    /*************************************************************
     *        js of Complex headers with column visibility        *
     *************************************************************/

    $('.column-visibility').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "visible": false,
            "targets": -1
        }]
    });

    /************************************
     *        js of Language file        *
     ************************************/

    $('.language-file').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
        }
    });


    /***************************************
     *        js of Setting defaults        *
     ***************************************/
    var defaults = {
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": false
    };


    $('.setting-defaults').dataTable($.extend(true, {}, defaults, {}));



    /*******************************************
     *        js of Row created callback        *
     *******************************************/


    $('.created-callback').DataTable({
        "createdRow": function(row, data, index) {
            if (data[5].replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 > 150000) {
                $('td', row).eq(5).addClass('highlight');
            }
        }
    });

    /********************************************
     *        js of Order by the grouping        *
     ********************************************/

    var groupingTable = $('.row-grouping').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "visible": false,
            "targets": 2
        }],
        "order": [
            [2, 'asc']
        ],
        "displayLength": 25,
        "drawCallback": function(settings) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows({
                page: 'current'
            }).nodes();
            var last = null;

            api.column(2, {
                page: 'current'
            }).data().each(function(group, i) {
                if (last !== group) {
                    $(rows).eq(i).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );

                    last = group;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('.row-grouping tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function() {
        var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
        if (currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
            table.order([2, 'desc']).draw();
        }
        else {
            table.order([2, 'asc']).draw();
        }
    });


    /***********************************************
     *        js of Order by footer callback        *
     ***********************************************/

    $('.footer-callback').DataTable({
        "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function(i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column(4)
                .data()
                .reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column(4, {
                    page: 'current'
                })
                .data()
                .reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

            // Update footer
            $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
                '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
            );
        }
    });


    /**********************************************
     *        js of custom toolbar elements        *
     **********************************************/


    $('.custom-toolbar-elements').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    });

    $("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');


    /**********************************
     *        js of File export        *
     **********************************/

    $('.file-export').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
    $('.buttons-copy, .buttons-csv, .buttons-print, .buttons-pdf, .buttons-excel').addClass('btn btn-primary mr-1');

});
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, react works with its own internal DOM representation while jQuery works directly on the actual page DOM. This makes the two philosophies incompatible and therefore it's highly unlikely you'll be able to get both to work together without a lot of extra effort and probably lots of hacks. Instead you should look for a library written for react that can achieve what you want like e.g. [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. React has its own DOM, which is not the 'real' dom. It is probably best to let go of the way you are doing things with JQuery and instead adopt the React way of doing this. Trying to work 'against' the framework will only end op causing you lots of problems.

If you want to use table implementation from an external source, try using material UI or react-bootstrap.

Comment: jQuery  used on another components also in my template(eg: chart,table,animations etc). 
as per your talk i want to replace all the jquery element with react libraries?

Comment: Yes, replace with react components. Specifically for datatables, you can find an npm module to replace those with react. It will look cleaner too